# Flask - detect disconnection

Tags: python-2.7, flask

Is there any way to detect when the user close/refresh the web?
My program look something like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template('form_ConfusionSet_submit.html')
@app.route('/hello/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello():
    some action...
    return render_template('form_action.html', text=text)

@app.route('/add/', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    some action...
    return render_template('form_text_submit.html',USER = USER)
```

I need to delete some files from the server when the user exit(no matter in whice step).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). There are a few packages to accomplish this in Flask, but here's [Flask-SocketIO](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

From the [example on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/tree/master/example), the [`socketio.on('connect')` decorator](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/example/app.py#L77) is used on a method that is called whenever a client connects to the backend. [`socketio.on('disconnect')` decorator](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/example/app.py#L82) is called whenever a client *disconnects* from the backend.

Using these, you can perform actions when a client connects and disconnects from your service.