# Close flask application when browser gets closed

Tags: python, flask

I have created a flask app that has been bundled into an exe file with Pyinstaller (not running in production server at all). It works properly, but when I close the browser hosting the flask app, the exe file is still running in the background so it has not been destroyed. I thought of putting code that destroys the process, but I noticed that no code gets executed after running:

```
app.run()
```

I was looking for some easy way to detect that the browser has been closed so the flask app should be closed as well. But it seems like I would either need to install selenium and detect when the browser is closed, or do some threading to keep checking if browser is opening. But these ideas seem kinda overkill.

Comment: You could have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364732/flask-detect-disconnection